# SMTP Сервер

Tags: python, sendmail

Вот я поставил себе Sendmail:
sudo apt-get install sendmail
Как теперь настроить SMTP сервер, надо узнать адрес,логин,пароль, чтобы отправить письмо через Python

Comment: Локально достаточно вызова бинарника sendmail.

На инет машины лучше ставить postfix или exim.

Comment: Ну у меня вообще desktop(Ubuntu), при установке postfix ошибка:
http://hashcode.ru/questions/198961/ubuntu-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-postfix

Comment: ну так вы на вопросы не отвечаете же там) да и не написано что там за ошибка)

Comment: > надо узнать адрес,логин,пароль ... Так вам от имени вашего почтового ящика нужно отправить?

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю что тебе поможет этот пример:

```
import smtplib
a=str(input('to mail ---> '))
b=str(input('text ---> '))
c=str(input('your mail ---> '))
d=str(input('password --->'))
s=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
s.starttls()
s.login(c,d)
print('login complete')
for i in range(1,16):
    s.sendmail(c,a,(b+str(i)))
    print(i)
s.quit()
```